# Revalue in R with a default

Tags: r, regex, plyr

I'm using the `Revalue` function from the `plyr` package to reassign the names of a long character vector, as in the example below:

```
sites <- c("example1.com","example2.com","facebook.com","google.com","example3.com")
replace <- c(facebook.com = "Facebook", google.com = "Google")
revalue(sites,replace)
# [1] "example1.com" "example2.com" "Facebook"     "Google"       "example3.com"
```

However, I'd also like to replace all the examples with "other", so what I'd really like to obtain is:

```
# [1] "other" "other" "Facebook"     "Google"       "other"
```

But I can't take the time to include every single site in my `replace` vector. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative

```
> sites <- gsub("\\.com$", "", sites)
> ifelse(sites %in% c("facebook", "google"), sites, "other")
[1] "other"    "other"    "facebook" "google"   "other"
```

Comment: Thanks -- `ifelse` will work great for me (though i will still need to use `Revalue`, since my replacements are more complex).

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapvalues() for replacing multiple levels, followed by revalue() for single levels:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
sites %>%
mapvalues(from=c("example1.com", "example2.com", "example3.com"), to=c(rep("other",3))) %>% 
revalue(replace)
```